# Can't set datagrid's selected item after refreshing page

Tags: wpf, datagrid, refresh

it got a weird problem... i got some data from a database bound to a datagrid. When i perfrom some upgrades the datagrid does not get (but the database does) until i refresh the page.
So i wanted to use

```
    temp = theGrid.SelectedItem
    Me.NavigationService().Refresh()
    theGrid.SelectedItem = temp
```

But it does not work....it seems like Navigationservice.Refresh forces the application to restart completely after the sub is done.

You guys got any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You said ...`it seems like Navigationservice.Refresh forces the application to restart completely after the sub is done` ... can you please tell us what `Me.NavigationService()` is? And is it setting the `ItemsSource` of the datagrid when `Refresh` is called?

Comment: It is a better practice to bind to public properties and implement iNotifyPropertChanged for dynamic update of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationService.Refresh` tells it to refresh the content (ie. redraw the content), it does not tell it to refresh the **data**.  You need to refresh your data source instead.  If you can show some code that relates to how you're loading your data, I may be able to offer some advice in that regard.

Comment: My Datasource is a DataSet, filled by Tableadapters. But when I refill the set manually a new sub starts which handles thegrid.SelectedCellChanged and there happens an error, because it can't get all the information it needs (ID e.g.). I've done this because the datagrid has the function of a navigation and shows some childrows which always refresh themselves when a new item on the navigationgrid is clicked.